# How to edit uploaded image with minimagick, that image is uploaded to active_storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing Web application, with Ruby on Rails, which is to add text to image uploaded by user. Right now I have no idea how to edit image with minimagick. What I want to ask is that how to get and edit the image which is uploaded to active_storage.

Code I wrote is here:

Gemfile

```
ruby '2.5.3'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'html2slim'

gem 'carrierwave'
gem "mini_magick"
```

index.html.slim

```
.text
  p Upload Image

= form_for @picture, url: {action: "create"} do |f|
  = f.file_field :image
  = f.submit 'Submit'
```

pictures_controller.rb

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @picture = Picture.new
  end

  def show
    @picture = Picture.find_by(uuid: params[:id])
  end

  def create
    text = 'this is test text'
    image = picture_params[:image]
    @picture = Picture.new(uuid: SecureRandom.uuid, image: picture_params[:image])
    new_image = @picture.build_collage_image(text).tempfile.open.read
    send_data new_image, :type => 'image/png', :disposition => 'inline'
  end


  private

  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:image, :ogp)
  end
end
```

models/picture.rb

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  include CollageMaker
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  after_save :build_collage_image
  has_one_attached :collaged_image
  has_one_attached :image

  def build_collage_image(text)
    CollageMaker.build(url_for(self.image), text)
  end
end
```

concerns/collage_maker.rb

```
module CollageMaker
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  FONT = './app/assets/fonts/cinecaption226.ttf'.freeze
  GRAVITY = 'center'
  TEXT_POSITION = '0,0'
  FONT_SIZE = 65
  INDENTION_COUNT = 16
  ROW_LIMIT = 8

  def self.build(image_url, text)
    text = prepare_text(text)
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(image_url)
    image.combine_options do |config|
      config.font FONT
      config.fill 'white'
      config.gravity GRAVITY
      config.pointsize FONT_SIZE
      config.draw "text #{TEXT_POSITION} '#{text}'"
    end
  end

  private
  def self.prepare_text(text)
    text.to_s.scan(/.{1,#{INDENTION_COUNT}}/)[0...ROW_LIMIT].join("\n")
  end
end
```

When test them, got this error.

[image]

Comment: As per the gem requirements, have got ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick command line tool installed?  Go to a terminal command line and try `convert -version`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn thanks to comment! I have already installed them. When check `convert -version` ,  infos about ImageMagick have returned as expected.

Comment: I think the issue might be that `url_for` is returning the full external path... try `url_for(self.image, only_path: true)`

Comment: returned `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)`. It might be that it's not right how to use `url_for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url_for` is the view context path to the image.

To access the image internally, you need to use `rails_blob_path`

From the documentation...

> If you need to create a link from outside of controller/view context
>   (Background jobs, Cronjobs, etc.), you can access the rails_blob_path
>   like this:
>
> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(user.avatar,
>   only_path: true)

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html